# manage views in Document library having folder structure

Tags: 2013, document-library, list-view

we are having a document library in SharePoint 2013, with multiple folders(having main folder->inside another folder->inside another folder->inside having documents), at the folder level's we are able to see the Name,Modified and modified by.
But we don't want to show modified by at folder level, we want to show it in the documents value place only.

Can any one help on this.

Regards,
Phani

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can have different views in a folder but you can in a document set (Document set being a folder with meta data).

If you want a native SP way of doing this:

Step 1: Add document sets to the library.

Step 2: Edit the options in the document set type and give the contents a separate view.

Step 3: Have a workflow that runs daily that changes folders into documents (set document type to Document Set) which will convert your current and future folders into document sets.

This is handy as by default sets can not be inside other sets but by ocnverting existing documents into sets you can get around this.